# render bug or my mistake?: overflow-hidden-zero-height sticking out of Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, html-rendering

#### I wonder if I am doing something wrong or this qualifies as a flex bug... (current chrome 65.03 under Ubuntu)

```
<main>
The outer container...
<section class="collapsible">
    <button className='buttonA'>Click me</button>
</section>
</main>
Some more text...
```

[image]

## [→ Source (codepen)](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/ZjGBbP?editors=1100)

**Well:** The dashed `main` is a flexbox.

`.collapsible` is an element with a height of zero and a colored line at top and bottom (thus: clearly no margin-collapse-issues here), an explicit `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden`. Dev tools inspection confirm that height of zero.

**Still:** its innertia (a button styled to `height:220px`) evidently has an outside effect. Not at all to its surrounding `.collapsible` but to main...

Pretty odd to me. Reminds me of classic margin-collapse-pains (or clearing floats gone pretty wrong). The issue is easily fixable by setting main to `display: block` but I still would like to know why...

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue. Can you provide a snippet with your html and css?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. [also added above](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/ZjGBbP?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the baseline alignment. You set `align-items: baseline` on the `main`-selector. It seems to work properly for other values of the `align-items` property.

I have no time to read up more on flexbox baselines atm, but I'm pretty sure a more detailed explanation can be found here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines

```css
html {
  font-family: sans;
  font-size: 1.4em cosmetic;
}

main {
  border: 4px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: initial;
}

.collapsible {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsible-inner {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.6);
}

button {
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
Flex elements appears to have a »radiation« affekt going beyond a height-0-element two levels up. Investigating...<br/>&nbsp;<br/>

<main>
The outer container...
<section class="collapsible">
    <button className='buttonA'>Click me</button>  
</section>
</main>
Some more text...
```

Comment: Ah. Good catch. So baseline makes sure, everyone (would) fit on it...
still odd, this »stings« through a height-0 one...|